# get checkbox and label aligned with background

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am having trouble getting a custom checkbox and a label to align correctly with the background being the same size as the checkbox. '

#### What I'm trying to achieve: [image]

```css
  
form
  display: block

input[type="checkbox"]
  display: none
  
  + label
    transition: all 300ms ease
    font-size: 2rem
    cursor: pointer
    background-color: red
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none
    -khtml-user-select: none
    -webkit-user-select: none
    -ms-user-select: none
    user-select: none
    i
      color: #bdc3c7
      font-size: 5.5rem
    &:checked + label
      transition: all 300ms ease
      background-color: #cc0000
      padding: 0
   i
    color: white
    animation: check 1s

label
  height: 100px
  vertical-align: bottom
  position: relative
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>

  <h5>Custom Checkboxes</h5>

  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"/>
  <label for="myCheckbox">
    <i class="ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank"></i> I would like to receive future emails from you*
  </label>

</form>
```

#### Here is a [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/t0nylombardi/pen/jbwyjY).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, mates.  No need to add extra brackets or semicolons!!

```
<form>

  <h5>Custom Checkboxes</h5>

  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"/>
    <label for="myCheckbox">
      I would like to receive future emails from you*
    </label>

</form>


  input[type="checkbox"]
    display: none

  label
    transition: all 300ms ease
    font-size: 2.1rem
    cursor: pointer
    background:
      color: red
    padding-bottom: 4px
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none
    -khtml-user-select: none
    -webkit-user-select: none
    -ms-user-select: none
    user-select: none

  label:before
    content: "\f374"
    font-family: "IonIcons"
    color: #000
    font-size: 3.4rem
    display: inline-block
    vertical-align: middle

  input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label
    transition: all 300ms ease
    background-color: darken(red, 10)

  input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before
    content: "\f371"
```